# How do I get POST values in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, postback

In ASP.net C#, I can get the value that a user typed into a form named `txtName` with `Request.Form["txtName"]`.

How do I get the value with javascript / jquery?

I've tried `$('#txtName').val()`, but this gives me the value specified in the HTML markup, not the value that the user entered and submitted.

Comment: Try this: After the postback is completed, and you confirm the textbox has the value you expect. View the HTML for the input element in (f12 is a handy way to see this) and post the markup as an edit to the question. I bet you will see the issue immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The data isn't exposed to any API JavaScript can access.

You would have to use something server side to include it somewhere in the DOM, or generate a `<script>` element that stores it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$('#txtName').val()`
**before** submit, it should hold the value entered by the user.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($('#txtName').val());
});
```

If that doesn't work, check if the form element has really the id 'txtName'. If not, this jquery selector works: $("form [name=txtName]")

The data can be stored before submit in a cookie/[web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage)

Comment: This is on the page that loads after the submit

Comment: Confusing start post. But ofcourse it only works before submit.